# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\TestProject\EditProfile.php on line 39

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error message when I am submitting the changes of the user info. 
Do I have to change the connection of the other page code:
I user to use mysqli_real_escape_string() and it was working fine:

mysqli_connect.php

```
             <?php
            /* @ suppresses error messages*/
            class Database
            {
                private $LOCAL_DB=0;

                protected  $dbc = NULL;

                public function getConnection()
                {

                    if (!$this->LOCAL_DB){
                        if($this->dbc==NULL)
                          $this->dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',NULL,'TestProject');

                       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                            die('b0ther');
                        }

                    }   
                    else
                    {
                       $this->dbc = @mysqli_connect(localhost,'root','','test');
            ////@ is an error suppression operator   
                       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                            die('b0ther');
                        }
                    }

                    return $this->dbc;
                }

                 public function closeDB()
                {
                     mysqli_close($this->dbc);  
                }

             }

            /* this file should be stored outside of the web directory for security purposes - this will
             * prevent a web browser from being able to see it
             */

            //print_r($dbc);

            /*$mySQL = 'SELECT * from test.Users;';
            $res = mysqli_query($mySQL, $dbc);

            if($res == FALSE)
                echo "Query Failed";

            mysqli_close($dbc) or die('close db failed');

             */
            ?>
```

EditProfile.php

```
            <?php

            $page_title = 'Edit User Profile User';

            include 'header.php';

            echo '<h1>Edit Profile</h1>';

            include "mysqli_connect.php";

            $db = new Database();
            $dbc = $db->getConnection();

            $id = $_SESSION['userID'];


            if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

                $userFname;
                $userLname;
                $userAddress1;
                $userAddress2;
                $userAddress3;
                $userPhone;
                $userImage;
                $userEmail;
                $userName;


                $errorMsg;
                $dbc = null;


                $errors = array();

                if (empty($_POST['userFname']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a first name';
                else
                    $userFname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userFname']));


                if (empty($_POST['userLname']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a last name';
                else
                    $userLname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userLname']));


                  if (empty($_POST['userName']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a username';
                else
                    $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userName']));


                if (empty($_POST['userEmail']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter email address';
                else
                    $userEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userEmail']));


                if (empty($_POST['userPhone']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a phone number';
                else
                    $userPhone = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userPhone']));


                if (empty($_POST['userAddress1']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter address line 1';
                else
                    $userAddress1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userAddress1']));


                if (empty($_POST['userAddress2']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter address line 2';
                else
                    $userAddress2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userAddress2']));


                if (empty($_POST['userAddress3']))
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter address line 3';
                else
                    $userAddress3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userAddress3']));

                if (!empty($errors)) {
                    echo '<p class="error"> The following errors occurred: <br />';

                    foreach ($errors as $err) {
                        echo "$err <br />";
                    }

                    echo '</p>';
                } else { //update the user

                    $q = "update users set userFname='$UserFname', userLname='$userLname',userName='$userName', userEmail='$UserEmail',userPhone='$UserPhone',userAdress1='$userAdress1', userAdress2='$userAdress2',userAdress3='$userAdress3',where userID = $id";

                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);


                    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
                        //print success message
                        echo '<p class="info"> User information updated Successfully!</p>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="error"> Error occured - User not updated</p>';
                        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '</p>';
                        echo '<p>' . $q . '</p>';
                    }
                }
            } // end if submitted conditional
            //else
            //always show form {
                $q = "SELECT userFname, userLname, userName, userEmail, userImage, userPhone, userAddress1 , userAddress2, userAddress3 from users where userID = $id";


                echo '<br>';

                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);


                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);


                $userPic = $row[4];


                //show avatar
                echo '<center> <img src="' .'./images/'.  $userPic  . '"height="150" width="150" ></center><br><br>';

                //print form
                echo' 
                    <div id="stylized" class="myform">

            <form action="EditProfile.php" method="post">


                <div align="center">
                      <fieldset>
                    <h3>Edit User: ' . $row[0] . ' ' . $row[1] . '</h3>
                    <br />
                       <label>First Name</label>  <input type="text" name="userFname" value="' . $row[0] . '" />
                      <br> <label>Last Name</label>  <input type="text" name="userLname" value="' . $row[1] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>User Name</label> <input type="text" name="userName" value="' . $row[2] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>Email Address</label> <input type="text" name="userEmail" value="' . $row[3] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>Phone number</label> <input type="text" name="userPhone" value="' . $row[5] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>Address 1</label> <input type="text" name="userAddress1" value="' . $row[6] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>Address 2</label> <input type="text" name="userAddress2" value="' . $row[7] . '"/>
                      <br> <label>Address 3</label> <input type="text" name="userAddress3" value="' . $row[8] . '"/>
                           ';
                            echo'
                  <div align="center">

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class ="DB4Button" align ="center" />


                     <input type ="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
                     <input type ="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '"/>
                             </div>
                              </fieldset>

                     </form>
                     </div>';

            echo '<br />';

            echo '<h2><a href="EditAvatar.php">Change Avatar</a></h2>';
            echo '<a href="ChangePassword.php"><img src=" pass.png "height="30" width="40" >Change Password</a>';


            include 'footer.html';
            ?>
```

Comment: And there's no error messages at all? Try echoing the error function to double check. Clearly the connection is failing.

Comment: Why do you have `$dbc = null;`?

Comment: Why not just have a constructor that sets your database connection and not have to worry about all this wacky logic?

Comment: I'd also guess `$errorMsg; $dbc = null;` is going to cause issues when you try to later on use it like `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);` .. because that is no longer a mysqli connection instance, it's a null (which is what your error says)